# SWUpdate ERROR : feature 'archive' required

Tags: yocto, bitbake, imx6, swupdate

I am attempting to use SWUpdate to update my device kernel and device tree. However I am getting the error `ERROR : feature 'archive' required`. I have been told to configure SWUpdate to include archive then build it. To do this I run `bitbake -c menuconfig swupdate`. This creates a `.config` file which I use as a `defconfig`.

I have my bitbake file `swupdate_%.bbappend` which places this into the build

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
DEPENDS += " libarchive zstd"
```

My question is how do I properly configure and compile the SWUpdate recipe to include the archive library?

If I run `bitbake -c menuconfig swupdate` and enable ZSTD, archive, and SystemD followed by `bitbake swupdate` I get errors that `zstd`, `archive` and `systemd` headers cannot be found. Edit 1: This is resolved by adding `DEPENDS += " libarchive zstd systemd"` to the bitbake file. This then breaks my overall build. So it seems my real issue is I cannot properly get the `defconfig` into my image.

I found many repos on GitHub and I copied their folder structure and used their bitbake files to inspire my own. However when I get to building I get the error mentioned above. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am willing to share more if needed.

Edit 2: I removed the `defconfig` from here and my project. I found that SWUpdate supports the function `bitbake -c diffconfig swupdate`. After making my changes I get an output file `/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/swupdate/2021.11-r0/fragment.cfg` with the contents

```
CONFIG_SYSTEMD=y
CONFIG_ZSTD=y
CONFIG_ARCHIVE=y
CONFIG_LOCALE=y
```

I added this to my `defconfig` and built my image. Same issue.

Edit 3: I want to show how I build my image.

```
source setup-environment build-fb/
bitbake -c cleanall mainapplication-dev
bitbake mainapplication-dev
```

I take the image generated and program my SD card. Then I run

```
bitbake -c cleanall smg-image-swu
bitbake smg-image-swu
```

This creates my `.swu` file which I place onto the device using FileZilla. I then run `swupdate -v -i smg-image-swu-imx6ull14x14evk.swu` and get the following output:

```
root@imx6ull14x14evk:~# swupdate -v -i smg-image-swu-imx6ull14x14evk.swu
Swupdate v2021.11.0

Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed copyright notices.

[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [main] : Running on smg-mx6 Revision 1.0
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] : Registered handlers:
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     dummy
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     flash
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     lua
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     raw
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     rawfile
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     rawcopy
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     shellscript
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     preinstall
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [print_registered_handlers] :     postinstall
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [listener_create] : creating socket at /tmp/swupdateprog
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [network_initializer] : Main loop daemon
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [listener_create] : creating socket at /tmp/sockinstctrl
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [network_thread] : Incoming network request: processing...
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE started :  Software Update started !
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [network_initializer] : Software update started
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [extract_file_to_tmp] : Found file
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [extract_file_to_tmp] :   filename sw-description
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [extract_file_to_tmp] :   size 384
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [get_common_fields] : Version 0.1.0
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [parse_hw_compatibility] : Accepted Hw Revision : 1.0
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [_parse_files] : Found compressed File: evccapplication-dev-imx6ull14x14evk.tar.gz --> / (/dev/update)
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [_parse_scripts] : Found Script: update.sh
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR : feature 'archive' required for 'evccapplication-dev-imx6ull14x14evk.tar.gz' in sw-description is absent!
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR : Compatible SW not found
[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [1] Image invalid or corrupted. Not installing ...
[TRACE] : SWUPDATE running :  [network_initializer] : Main thread sleep again !
[INFO ] : No SWUPDATE running :  Waiting for requests...
[INFO ] : SWUPDATE running :  [endupdate] : Swupdate *failed* !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to edit the above bbappend file to

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
DEPENDS += " libarchive zstd"
```

Comment: How did you figure out these were the needed DEPENDS etc?

Trying to fix the same error but for `feature 'copy' required for '' in sw-description is absent!`

Comment: I am not 100% sure how I figured this out. In the end my issue was not with the archives, it was with partition space on the SD card.